# PuTTY Network Timeout Error

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm using PuTTY on my Windows machine to use SSH on my university server. I run analyses that take up to 3 days to complete. I can connect and start the analyses but eventually get an error message 'PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort'. I have problem solved this - the issue lies with the period of inactivity on PuTTY where it is running the analyses. The network connections ect are all fine. At the moment the only way I can get the analyses to complete is to press enter every couple of hours. This really is annoying as I have to get up during the night!

I'm not a computer whizz whatsoever and would really apprentice if anyone could suggest a solution.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following methods (I prefer the second but YMMV)

1. Prevent timeout

   - Fiddle with Putty's settings such as `Enable TCP Keepalives` and `seconds between keepalives`.
   - Tell the shell not to get bored (`unset TMOUT`)
2. Change what you are doing so you don't hold a session open while inactive for several days

   - [output redirection (`>`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing))
   - [disconnecting STDIN from tty (`&`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line)
   - [prevent disconnection signalling the process (`nohup`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

e.g.

```
nohup ./my_analysis > analysis.out 2> analysis.err &; exit;
```

You can check progress by e.g. logging in again and using

```
tail -f analysis.out
```

More complicated needs can often be accomodated using named pipes.

---

Other references

- [how to make putty ssh connection never to timeout when user is idle?](https://askubuntu.com/q/254750/257118)
- [How to make putty to not break my session after some time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20193/how-to-make-putty-to-not-break-my-session-after-some-time)
- [PuTTY and how to keep alive telnet session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828853/putty-and-how-to-keep-alive-telnet-session)

Comment: Ah you're brilliant! Thanks ever so much, I can get a good nights sleep tonight :)

Comment: @Magpie101: Glad to help - See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) if it's available.

It would allow you do run whatever command within a screen session (which wouldn't timeout) and you'd be able to reconnect it later. A basic use could look like the following:

1. Run `screen`
2. Start analysis
3. Detach (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>) the screen (or wait for the timeout)
4. Reconnect later using `screen -r`